# dataTables fixed columns plugin NOT working

Tags: css, datatables, jquery-plugins, lost-focus

To share the files I have created a project on github repo link: https://github.com/shantanookirtane/dataTablesFixedColumns.git

This repository has index.html where the table gets loaded under the DOM structure similar to what is getting created when I run my application. The repo has all necessary css and js files.

I have add the exact issue description in README.md file on github for this project, pasting the same here again.

Datatable version: 1.9.1
Datatable Fixed column version: 3.0.2

Issue with DataTables Fixed columns

The issue here is that even though the scroll bar is appearing the left column is not fixed, so when you move the scroll bar everything moves.

Also if you click on the first TH element in table i.e. (ServerName) the table horizontally expands and contradicts. during this process if you notice carefully the scroll bar get applied to first the outer div with class=tab-content and then to div with class dataTables_scrollBody

I am looking for a solution here so that I can use the Datatable Fixed column plugin successfully

### Update

So now I have updated the datatables v to 1.10 and pushed the code to the same location in gitlab. Although now the fixedColumns pluging is working but not smoothly.

Following are the issues which I am facing now:

1. The table gets rendered into DIV with vertical and horizontal scroll bar which does not look good.

Now if you click on first TH element in the table i.e. left most top corner cell the vertical scroll bar vanishes and table appears properly. but the FixedColumn is NOT yet started working.

Now if you lose focus from this table and if you come back you will notice that the FixedColumns plugin started working smoothly.

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest DataTable version 1.10? Fixed Columns work in the latest version (I'm using them)

Comment: That is NOT a option for me given the timelines, but does that mean that the FixedColumns plugin does NOT work with dataTables 1.9.1 ?

Comment: Also do you know if with dataTables 1.10 can use jquery 1.9 ?

Comment: Jquery 1.9 works - this is helpful: http://www.datatables.net/upgrade/1.10

I couldn't get fixed columns working on datatables 1.9 - so I upgraded - I may have done something stupid though and that's why it didn't work -

Comment: I looked at your sources and noticed that you're never actually calling the FixedColumns. You assign the handler after it's relevant - you have to define fnInitComplete as part of your dataTable definitions. 
you also call FixedColumns wrong - you need to do this like so:
 new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(..whatever ...)
These changes won't make things work but they get you closer to where you need to be!

Comment: Are you suggesting that I am not at all calling the FixedColumns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61499/discussion-between-birgit-martinelle-and-shantanoo-k).

Comment: Cant chat now, in office :)

Comment: I have downloaded the datatables v 1.10, but now whenever I am calling FixedColumns plugin like below I am getting error as `Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( opts ) {
  return $(this).dataTable( opts ).api();
 } has no method '_fnConstruct`   My initialzation : `$.fn.DataTable.FixedColumns( dcInfoDataTable, {
             "iLeftColumns": 1,
             "heightMatch": "none",
             "iRightColumns": 0
           } );`

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mh1e5vyv/ you can see the issue I am facing mentioned in the post

Comment: When I try to load your fiddle I get this error: DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
this happens when the data doesn't match the column definitions

Comment: Yeah, thats true in my case, because I am setting up the data for each cell in my createRow callback method. If you say ok to that warning it still loads the table....

Comment: Ok - I think i figured out your issue: You are not including the bootstrap - datatable CSS file :)
http://jsfiddle.net/bmartinelle/wor9afo0/2/ - I added it and now i am seeing really strange behavior  - if you resize the output window they columns do update and your left column gets frozen
If you fix the first issue this may be resolving the problem with the non-freezing on startup too.
Here's a link to the css in question: //cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css

Comment: which jsfiddle link you provided in your latest comment? and sorry but I did not get your comments either :(

Comment: Oh sorry - too many fiddles going: http://jsfiddle.net/mh1e5vyv/2/
You have to include a special css file (//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.boo‌​tstrap.css) to ensure that your datatables work well with bootstrap.
If you add this css file you will see that your table starts working.
It doesn't work right away - you have to resize the display window in the fiddle. I believe that's because of the other error I pointed out before.

Comment: Ok, currently in my application I am using boostrap 2.3 so is dataTables 1.10 compatible wih 2.3 or I have to upgrade bootstrap too.. Also any idea why the vertical scroll comes initially and then vanishes when clicked on first TH element.

Comment: I believe there is some CSS that was written for bootstrap 2.3 - but i am not certain. Upgrading bootstrap could be quite be quite an effort depending on the size of your codebase