# Issue while using FixedColumns plugin with datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables v 1.10 and fixedColummns v 3.0.2. Below is my code

// Creating datatable

```
var dcInfoDataTable = contentDiv.find('table.dcInfoTable').DataTable( {
                        "aaData": resultMap[dc],
                        "iDisplayLength": 10,
                        "bLengthChange": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": true,
                        "bProcessing": false, 
                        "sScrollX": "100%",
                        "bScrollCollapse": true,
                        "bDeferRender": true,
                        "sScrollXInner":"100%",
                        "aoColumnDefs": aoColumnDefs,
                        "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
                            if (aData["comments"] && aData["comments"].indexOf("Error") != -1) {
                                // Do not do anything 
                                $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(aData["serverName"]+"" +
                                "<a class='btn btn-danger' href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Error in execution'><i class='icon-question'></i></a>");

                            } else {
                                _(aoColumnDefs.length).times(function(n) {
                                    var cnt = n+1;
                                    if ($('td:eq('+cnt+')', nRow).length != 0) {
                                        var className = $('td:eq('+cnt+')', nRow).attr("class");
                                        var arr = className.split("~");
                                        // possible that not all servers has same mount 
                                        if (server_mountedOn[aData["serverName"]+"~"+arr[0]]) {
                                            $('td:eq('+cnt+')', nRow).html(server_mountedOn[aData["serverName"]+"~"+arr[0]][arr[1]]);  
                                        } else {
                                            $('td:eq('+cnt+')', nRow).html(" - ");
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

// Calling fixedColumns plugin to freeze column

```
$.fn.DataTable.FixedColumns(dcInfoDataTable);
```

When this code is getting executed I am getting below error in Chrome console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( opts ) {
    return $(this).dataTable( opts ).api();
} has no method '_fnConstruct'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(...)`?

Comment: Tried that too, same issue :(

Comment: Are you sure you added your fixedColumns script properly (see correct order in [documentation](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/examples/simple.html))? Try it with as simple data table as possible just to make it work. It looks like error states that fixedColumns is not there.

Comment: So it worked with new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(...), But now the columns is not fixed, the whole table has scroll bar :(

Comment: Create a simple jsfiddle that reproduces the issue, maybe I'll be able to help you then. Now it's just impossible to guess what's wrong.

Comment: @llya Can you please refer to this link where originally I have ask this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898855/datatables-fixed-columns-plugin-not-working?noredirect=1#comment40563442_25898855    I have added the latest code in gitlab you can download and test the problem

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/mh1e5vyv you can see the issue I am facing mentioned in the post –